# Test condition on a string, conversion

Tags: r, string, type-conversion

I know that could be a simple question. I have been looking around but I havent found a proper answer.

I have a data frame with strings

```
V1   V2
LZZA LSGR
JUTZ AABB
LKUZ TZBN
```

And I would like to test

```
ifelse(V1 > V2, "ok","no)
```

However I dont know how to convert V1 and V2 as factors without losing the string.

If I apply `as.numeric(as.character(V1))` it's replace by NA. The same if I use `data.matrix(V1)`

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Are you saying that you have `factor` columns?  If that is the case `with(df1, ifelse(as.character(V1) > as.character(V2), "ok","no"))`

Comment: Sorry @akrun for this stupid question its exactly what i needed. Thanks for answering my requests 